# Trying to not get duplicate columns in my select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Using an inner join, how do I retrieve information using primary keys and foreign keys?

In my first table my primary key is `expertsID` and in my second table my foreign key is `expertsID`. When I execute the  sql statement to retrieve the information, it will show both `expertID` columns.
How do I make it so that only 1 column is shown?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM 
INNER JOIN experience ON experts.expertID = experience.expertID;
```

Comment: Best practice is to always specify the columns. The `*` is only for lazy debugging something.

Comment: 'A select list consisting only of a single unqualified * can be used as shorthand to select all columns from all tables:' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: There's a chance you will get multiple rows for each expert since the distinct clause will be over all columns in all tables where an expert has many experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the asterisk it is showing everything from both tables. Simply just select the columns you wish to see. Hope this helps you!

```
SELECT experts.expertID, experts.nextColumn, experience.someColumn 
FROM experts 
INNER JOIN experience 
ON experts.expertID = experience.expertID
```

Answer (score 1):

Right Now, you're selecting all columns from  the experts table. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT experts.expertID
FROM experts
INNER JOIN experience ON experts.expertID = experience.expertID;
```

This will get the distinct `expertIDs` from the `expert` table which satisfy the condition.